# Galera Cluster Database Sync, But not Table Data Problem

Tags: mariadb, database-replication, galera

I've got a (2) node galera setup and I'm having this weird issue where creating databases/tables works and replicates across the nodes, mean that if you create a database or a table under a database on one node 1, it will appear on node 2. But when data is inserted into database.table on node 1, it does not appear on node 2.

What could be the issue?

Comment: Can give give more information about what you've tried so far?

Comment: I think I see the issue. If I manually create the data, it replicates, but when I try to use mysql to load a dumpfile on just node1, the data doesn't replicate to node 2. Is there a way to force replication after a dumpfile load?

Comment: This would be: [mysql -u root -p < migration_data.sql]   When I import the data on node1, there is no data on node2.  It's just odd, because the database/tables get created on node2, but the data inside the tables is missing.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem. I was trying to load MYISAM dumps without converting them to INNODB.

Problem Solved and here is the quick conversion for anybody else impacted:

sed -i.bak 's#MyISAM#innodb#g' MIGRATION_DATA.sql